# Add rows to CSV file and save resulting CSV as TXT and keep original CSV as is

Tags: python, csv, file-io

I am new to Python and currently struggling with this task. I don't want to use advanced tools such as pandas or object oriented programming to do this just yet.

I have a CSV file and I need to add additional rows. But when I run the code below all values are added in the last cell of the last row as shown below.

[image: Output]

Here is my code. What I am doing wrong?
import csv

## Greet the user and ask her to enter a file name:

print 'Hello'
source_file = str(input('Please enter a roster file: '))

name_counter = 1

## Asks for correct filename

csv_input = open(source_file, 'a')

## Asks uer if she wants to add additional names

name_bool = 
str(input('Would you like to enter additional names? (Y/N): '))

if name_bool == 'Y':

```
number_names = int(input('How many more names? '))  # The number of additional people to add

while name_counter <= number_names:
    first_name = str(input('First name: '))
    csv_input.write('{:10s}'.format(first_name, end=' '))

    last_name = str(input('Last Name: '))
    csv_input.write('{:10s}'.format(last_name, end=' '))

    person_age = str(input('Age: '))
    csv_input.write('{}'.format(int(person_age), end=' '))

    person_occupation = str(input('Occupation: '))
    csv_input.write('{:10s}'.format(person_occupation, end=' '))

    person_height = str(input('Height (in inches): '))
    csv_input.write('{}'.format(int(person_height), end=' '))

    person_weight = str(input('Weight (in pounds): '))
    csv_input.write('{}'.format(int(person_weight), end=' '))

    print '\n'

    name_counter = name_counter + 1
```

elif name_bool == 'N':

```
    # Close the file when we are done adding

print 'You are done'
```

csv_input.close()

Thanks folks to all your answers, I was able to fix my original issues.

However I want to keep the original CSV file as is. I want to add the additional rows to the CSV file in a new TXT file instead. In other words, I want to do the following:

1. Read the CSV file
2. Add rows to the CSV file
3. Save the resulting CSV file with the new rows as a TXT file but keep the original CSV file as is
4. So at the end I will have the original.csv file and a new original_expanded.txt

Comment: Why are you printing the values with `{:10s}` etc. formatting? Instead of simply the value, followed by a comma? And clearly you need a newline or two. Better still, if you can, use the `csv`  package.

Comment: Where is the new line in CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print ('Hello')
source_file = str(input('Please enter a roster file: '))
csv_input = open(source_file, 'a')
name_bool = str(input('Would you like to enter additional names? (Y/N): '))
if name_bool == 'Y':
    name_counter = 1
    number_names = int(input('How many more names? '))  # The number of additional people to add
    csv_input.write("\n")
    while name_counter <= number_names:
        first_name = str(input('First name: '))
        csv_input.write(first_name + ", ")

        last_name = str(input('Last Name: '))
        csv_input.write(last_name + ", ")

        person_age = str(input('Age: '))
        csv_input.write(person_age + ", ")

        person_occupation = str(input('Occupation: '))
        csv_input.write(person_occupation + ", ")

        person_height = str(input('Height (in inches): '))
        csv_input.write(person_height + ", ")

        person_weight = str(input('Weight (in pounds): '))
        csv_input.write(person_weight + "\n")

        print ('\n')

        name_counter = name_counter + 1
elif name_bool == 'N':
    print('You are done')

csv_input.close()
```

Comment: However I want to keep the original CSV file as is. I want to add the additional rows to the CSV file in a new TXT file instead. In other words, I want to do the following:

1. Read the CSV file
2. Add rows to the CSV file
3. Save the resulting CSV file with the new rows as a TXT file but keep the original CSV file as is
4. So at the end I will have the original.csv file and a new original_expanded.txt

Comment: Mohamed

  Just create a copy of the file and edit the copy or the original :)
```
from shutil import copyfile
copyfile(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a `csv_input.write('\n')` near `print('\n')`

Answer (score 0):

```
print ('Hello')
source_file = str(input('Please enter a roster file: '))
csv_input = open(source_file, 'a')
name_bool = str(input('Would you like to enter additional names? (Y/N): '))
if name_bool == 'Y':
    name_counter = 1
    number_names = int(input('How many more names? '))  # The number of additional people to add
    while name_counter <= number_names:
        first_name = str(input('First name: '))
        csv_input.write(first_name + ", ")

        last_name = str(input('Last Name: '))
        csv_input.write(last_name + ", ")

        person_age = str(input('Age: '))
        csv_input.write(person_age + ", ")

        person_occupation = str(input('Occupation: '))
        csv_input.write(person_occupation + ", ")

        person_height = str(input('Height (in inches): '))
        csv_input.write(person_height + ", ")

        person_weight = str(input('Weight (in pounds): '))
        csv_input.write(person_weight )

        csv_input.write('\n')

        name_counter = name_counter + 1
elif name_bool == 'N':
    print('You are done')

csv_input.close()
```